# Jquery getJSON populate select menu question

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, getjson

I am populating a select menu with getJSON.  I am wondering if there's a way that I can use jQuery's .each function to bring in these values?

Surely there must be an easier way to accomplish this...maybe?

PHP file:

```
<?php
    $queryMonth = "SELECT monthID, month FROM months";
    $result = $db->query($queryMonth);

      while($rowMonth = $db->fetch_assoc($result)) :
        $data[] = $rowMonth;
      endwhile;

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('selectMenus.php', function(data) {
  $("select.month").append("<option value=" + data[0].monthID + ">" + data[0].month + "</option>");
  $("select.month").append("<option value=" + data[1].monthID + ">" + data[1].month + "</option>");
  $("select.month").append("<option value=" + data[2].monthID + ">" + data[2].month + "</option>");
  $("select.month").append("<option value=" + data[3].monthID + ">" + data[3].month + "</option>");
  $("select.month").append("<option value=" + data[4].monthID + ">" + data[4].month + "</option>");
  $("select.month").append("<option value=" + data[5].monthID + ">" + data[5].month + "</option>");
  $("select.month").append("<option value=" + data[6].monthID + ">" + data[6].month + "</option>");
  $("select.month").append("<option value=" + data[7].monthID + ">" + data[7].month + "</option>");
  $("select.month").append("<option value=" + data[8].monthID + ">" + data[8].month + "</option>");
  $("select.month").append("<option value=" + data[9].monthID + ">" + data[9].month + "</option>");
  $("select.month").append("<option value=" + data[10].monthID + ">" + data[10].month + "</option>");
  $("select.month").append("<option value=" + data[11].monthID + ">" + data[11].month + "</option>");
});
```

My json output looks like this:

```
[{
  "monthID": "1",
  "month": "January"
}, {
  "monthID": "2",
  "month": "February"
}, {
  "monthID": "3",
  "month": "March"
}, {
  "monthID": "4",
  "month": "April"
}, {
  "monthID": "5",
  "month": "May"
}, {
  "monthID": "6",
  "month": "June"
}, {
  "monthID": "7",
  "month": "July"
}, {
  "monthID": "8",
  "month": "August"
}, {
  "monthID": "9",
  "month": "Septemeber"
}, {
  "monthID": "10",
  "month": "October"
}, {
  "monthID": "11",
  "month": "November"
}, {
  "monthID": "12",
  "month": "December"
}]
```

Comment: Can we see the markup for your select boxes?

Comment: @Scott, all of your comments are saying the select menus are empty. Have you verified that your selector is correct and actually returning the element(s) you're trying to alter..?

Comment: Based on @Richard and @karim79's answers...I got it to work.  I can still put the markup here if you'd like.

Comment: I had a few missing curly braces...that's why they were coming up empty.  Operator error...and I'm a noob with this jQuery stuff.

Comment: Some say jQuery is killing JavaScript programming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [@RaYell's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137467/rayell) method....this is what worked for me:

```
$.getJSON('months.php', function(data){
    var html = '';
    var len = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {html += '<option value="' + data[i].monthId + '">' +    data[i].month + '</option>';
    }
    $('select.month').append(html);
});
```

Thanks to everyone for your help on this!!

Answer (score 49):

```
$.getJSON('selectMenus.php', function(data){
    var html = '';
    var len = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
        html += '<option value="' + data[i].monthId + '">' + data[i].month + '</option>';
    }
    $('select.month').append(html);
});
```

Storing the HTML code in a variable and appending it only once at the end is very important if you care about your app performance.

Comment: RaYell...I ended up using your method.  I have more control with this.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SyaZ Yup, that was a typo. Thx for finding it.

Answer (score 16):

This should work:

```
   $.getJSON('selectMenus.php', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index,item) {
           $("select.month").append("<option value=" + item.monthID + ">" + item.month + "</option>"); 
    });
    });
```

Comment: This works great...I ended going with @RaYell's method.  I have greater control of how much data is brought in.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

From the great book [jQuery in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355),here is a way to do what you want writing a custom jQuery command:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.emptySelect = function() {
    return this.each(function(){
      if (this.tagName=='SELECT') this.options.length = 0;
    });
  }

  $.fn.loadSelect = function(optionsDataArray) {
    return this.emptySelect().each(function(){
      if (this.tagName=='SELECT') {
        var selectElement = this;
        $.each(optionsDataArray,function(index,optionData){
          var option = new Option(optionData.caption,
                                  optionData.value);
          if ($.browser.msie) {
            selectElement.add(option);
          }
          else {
            selectElement.add(option,null);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

And then:

```
$.getJSON('selectMenus.php', 
   function(data){
      $("select.month").loadSelect(data);
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++)
    $("select.month")
         .append("<option value=" + data[i].monthID + ">" + data[i].month + "</option>");
```

If you want to achieve maximum performance, you should reduce the DOM operations to a minimum, like this:

```
var html = [];

for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    html[html.length] = "<option value=";
    html[html.length] = data[i].monthID;
    html[html.length] = ">";
    html[html.length] = data[i].month;
    html[html.length] = "</option>";
}

$("select.month").append(html.join(''));
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in the last example, you should remove the ) after "</option>"

Comment: @googletorp thanks.  I managed to get it working...I appreciate it.