# How to change select box options from other select box through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a popup form that has two drop-down menus in it. Depending on the selected option in the first one, I have to change the possible options in the second. As the information is in the database, I have to check what the information through Ajax.

Here is for example a sample result:

```
$arr = {
    "1" => array("1","first","ref1"),
    "2" => array("2","second","ref2"),
    "3" => array("3","third","ref3")
};
```

Could you please help me with how to pass this array, and how to assign these options to the second select box.
I have the following code now and it works good. 
function onChangeBrand(){ 
var brandId = $('#brand').val(); 
$.ajax({ 
 type: "POST",
 datatype: 'json',
 url: "items/getModel", 
 data: {brandId : brandId},
 success: function(data) { 
    // 
 } 
}); 
} 
I receive a data that looks like a string containing the following information: 
[{"model_id":"5","name":"M1132"},{"model_id":"4","name":"ProBook 6470"}]

How could I transfer this information into an jquery array and pass it to the second drop-down menu as options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populate Select list Menu though Ajax Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688587/populate-select-list-menu-though-ajax-jquery)

Comment: give us more info, what kind of info is stored in the db? maybe it's quicker if you just load all the results from the database if they are not too much, save them in a variable and you wouldn't even need Ajax, just with some jquery could manage it.

Comment: Hi. The information is for a brand and for a model. Regarding the brand I select the model of the product. The information is going to become really big and I don'y want to have all it in the page.

Comment: I have the following code now and it works good.  function onChangeBrand(){

        var brandId = $('#brand').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            datatype: 'json',
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>items/getModel",
            data: {brandId : brandId},
            success: function(data) {
                //
            }
        });
    } I receive a data that looks like a string containing the following information: [{"model_id":"5","name":"M1132"},{"model_id":"4","name":"ProBook 6470"}]

Answer (score 0):

you can get a Json object from the server with some data and loop through them to create the options dynamically with Javascript:

```
for(var i in options){
  option       = $('<option>');
  option.value = options[i].value;
  option.append(options[i].text);
  select2.append(option);
}
```

Example working code in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/91j9Go0Yfjif6mScJT39?p=preview).
Hope this help.

Comment: yes, thank you, but the problem is that I can't get the "options" array. I can't transfer the php array to javascript array.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(data)` line 15 in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/91j9Go0Yfjif6mScJT39?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You can use try with this piece of code -

```
     var secondSelect=$('#secondselectid');
     var dataString=[{"model_id":"5","name":"M1132"}, {"model_id":"4","name":"ProBook 6470"}];    
     $(dataString).each(function(key,val){
         var selectoption=$('<option>');
         selectoption.value = val.model_id;
         selectoption.append(val.name);
        $(secondSelect).append(selectoption); 
      });
```