# Selecting from a database in a sub category when a category has been chosen in a form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, categories

I currently have this form - a snippet of which is below:

```
          <li>
            <label for="Catid">Pick a Category:</label>
            <select name="Catid">
              <?php
                  $Products = New Products();
                  $Products->form_Cat_Picker();
                ?>
            </select>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="Subcatid">Sub Category:</label>
            <select name="Subcatid">
              <?php
                  $Products = New Products();
                  $Products->form_Subcat_Picker();
                ?>
            </select>
```

Ok, so this then sends to products.php which in the products class does this:

```
function form_Cat_Picker() {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    }       
    $catPicker = "SELECT Catid, Catname
            FROM ProductCats
            ORDER BY Catid";
    if ($Result = $mysqli->query($catPicker)){
        if (!$Result) {
            echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }
        else {
            $Result = $mysqli->query($catPicker);
        }
        while ($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row["Catid"].'">'.$row["Catname"]."</option>";
        }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
function form_Subcat_Picker() {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    }       
    $catPicker = "SELECT Subcatid, Subcatname, Parentid
            FROM ProductSubCats
            ORDER BY Subcatid";
    if ($Result = $mysqli->query($catPicker)){
        if (!$Result) {
            echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }
        else {
            $Result = $mysqli->query($catPicker);
        }
        while ($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row["Subcatid"].'">'.$row["Subcatname"]."</option>";
        }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Both of these, essentially return a list of categories and sub categories from the database,  to populate the form's drop down list.

The problem is, I don't want the Sub categories to appear unless their parent was selected in the initial dropdown box. How can I achieve this? I currently have an extra column in the table ProductSubCats which is Parentid, and one in ProductCats which is Catid, and they connect up.

But how would I set a condition firstly to create a variable where an option/value is selected, and secondly to say "this variable $selected".I would know how to pass it through to that code and use a condition WHERE $selected = whatever, but it is getting to that point that confuses me. Thank you

EDIT - it seems my error is in forgetting php will run once on page load.
So I should have it present all of the data and then use jquery to only display those that have been selected. But I should also have a value of 0 and a blank entry as well. if for example I have a category with the value 1 and 2 sub categories with the parent id of 1 How would I have jquery show those subcats with the parent id of 1, and not say, those with the parent id of 2? After user selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to handle this, but most of them are in the frontend.

If you want to do this with PHP, then just check to see if $_POST['Catid'] is set, and have the first category auto-submit on change.  There's some coding around this behavior that you'll have to do.

If you want to accomplish this without a page load however, then you need to either use AJAX to try to populate the second select dynamically, or hide/filter the values.  In either case you'll probably want/need to use jQuery to make your life a lot simpler this way.

It seems like, however, you're forgetting that PHP is a server side language.  As a result, PHP can't populate the second select box after the user has a made a selection.  Javascript can, as it's run in the browser, or you can refresh/resubmit the page and take the POST data and use that, but PHP only "runs once" when the page is first hit, and will generate all the selections/data then.

Update:
If you're looking to do this the 'quick and dirty' way, you can populate each of your sub-category selects, and put them each inside a div.  Then, give them an ID of their parent-category, and set their visibility to false:

```
        <div id='parentId1' style="display:none">
        <select name="Subcatid">
          <?php
              $Products = New Products();
              $Products->form_Subcat_Picker();
            ?>
        </select>
        </div>
```

You now can set up an onChange function in the parent selector, which show/hides the appropriate other values `$("#parentId" + parentId).show()`. This will get you a lot of the way there, but if you take the time to learn how to do an AJAX call, it's pretty easy to do with jQuery and can probably get what you're looking for.  Here's a good SO question which shows how to do it:  [jquery getJson populate Select Menu Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502649/jquery-getjson-populate-select-menu-question)

Comment: Ok it seems that is where I have gone wrong. So I should have it present all of the data and set the conditions within jquery?

if for example I have a category with the value 1
and 2 sub categories with the parent id of 1

How would I have jquery show those subcats with the parent id of 1, and not say, those with the parent id of 2? After user selection?

Comment: If you don't want to use AJAX to dynamically populate the select statements (which is probably the best/cleanest way to handle this), then you just need to set the visibility of what you're looking for.  I'll update my answer with a bigger code block

Answer (score 1):

What you will want to do is create a default option and set it's value to 0

```
<select name="main">
    <option value="0">Please Select an Option...</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Next in your php you need to check if the user selected something

```
$selected = (int)$_POST["main"];
if(!empty($selected)){
    // They selected something other than 0
    // 0 is considered empty
}
```

if so get the sub result categories.