# Parse JSON Array File and Populate The Result Into Select

Tags: json

I'm doing Android PhoneGap project in my company.
I have a JSON file and want to get it into my HTML select box.
As I am still newbie, I haven't understand about JSON parsing mostly.

Here's my JSON File (city.json) :

```
[{"CityID":1,"CityName":"Magelang"},{"CityID":2,"CityName":"Jayapura"},{"CityID":3,"CityName":"Aceh"}]
```

I really didn't know whether it's needed to parsed or not.
I have followed RaYell answer in this thread.
[Jquery getJSON populate select menu question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502649/jquery-getjson-populate-select-menu-question)

So, I code these to populate the result into the option in select box.

```
$.getJSON('city.json', function(data){
var html = '';
var len = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
    html += '<option value="' + data[i].CityID + '">' + data[i].CityName + '</option>';
}
$('#city').append(html);
});
```

But it didn't worked on my code.
My select box has none options :(
Any solutions?
Thanks before.

Comment: `getJSON` parses it already.

Comment: so I don't need to parseJSON it first?

Comment: Nope you don't. Also can you put the HTML code for #city?

Comment: <select id="city" name="city" class="city"></select>

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `$('#city').html(html);` to see what the error is:

EDIT: Add this to the end of the `$.getJSON` call:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON(. . .).fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
             var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
             alert( "Request Failed: " + err);
             });
    });
```

Comment: still didn't work :(
just for info, #city is the id for my select box..
anyway, what's the different between .html and .append?

Comment: `html` will replace the inner html of `#city`. `append` will append the results. If it is empty already, I imagine it would just do the same thing.

Comment: Can you do `alert(data)` inside your function to make sure data contains info?

Comment: hmm I've tried it, but there's no alert..
    'for (var i in data) {
     alert(data);
     //html += '<option value="' + data[i].CityID + '">' + data[i].CityName + '</option>';
    }'

Comment: I edited my answer with some code to help see the error message.

Comment: I've tried it but nothing happens..The alert box didn't appear.. Am I missing any library so the code can't be compiled? I put that '$.getJSON' script on the head of the HTML.. Did I put it in the wrong place?

Comment: I changed my answer again to help you. Put your code inside `$(document).ready` to ensure that it runs when the page is loaded. You may be running into an issue where it attempts to set the html of an element that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: What will be the sign if the code was succesfully loaded? sorry for the dumb question..

Comment: If you try to add any arbitrary option to `#city` without the AJAX call and it doesn't show anything, then the JS is executing before that element has fully loaded. Using `$(document).ready` prevents this from happening by waiting for everything on the page to load before it executes the function passed to `ready`

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop won't work on objects. Only arrays.

You need to use `for (var i in data) {` to loop through all properties of an object.

Comment: still didn't work :(

Is it a directory problem? I put the JSON file in the same directory as the HTML file..

Comment: The data returned is a JSON array, so he would need to use a `for` loop, not `for in`.

Comment: @TheDude A JSON array? JSON is JavaScript Object Notation, so shouldn't be an array.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example. You will see that Array is a JSON basic type.

Comment: @TheDude +1 Right you are!